# Add one user to all protected ranges in all sheets at once?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is there a way/script to add one user to all protected ranges at once? Maybe through a script? Tedious as we have loads of workbooks with loads of sheets and I am required to enter one by one to add user :-(

Comment: The question is too broad and doesn't describe your search / research efforts. Do you already know how to create a script bounded to an Google Sheets' spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks Ruben, yes I know how to do this, but it would require to add the same script to each sheet. Isn't there a way to create a script that can run on a folder content, iterate through all sheets and add the user?

Comment: Yes there is. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts and include that you want to apply the protection to spreadsheets in a folder.